# Grails pass parameter from loop to controller

Tags: grails, gsp

In Grails I'm trying to delete a record from a (HTML) table, I want to achieve this by passing the ID of the object to the controller. So there is a table in HTML and the user clicks "delete" and the item is deleted from the database. (This logic works according to the unit tests, the problem is passing the ID from view -> controller)
I have tried several solutions found on here such as

```
<g:each in="${recipe}" var="item">
<tr>
   <td>
      ${item.recipeName}
   </td>
   <td>
      ${item.people}
   </td>
   <td>
      <g:link controller="UserRecipe" action="delete" params="[id: '${item.id}']" class="class">Info to Display</g:link></tr>
</g:each>
```

Which doesn't crash but calls the controller correctly, though the value of the id = null. When I manually edit the url and add /4 for example, the ID will be four. Several solutions on here showed how to pass parameters, but the error arrises when I try to pass a parameter which I access using the ${} notation with these solutions, e.g. using `createLink` and a `params` list, it will crash the application because it's a nested ${${}} it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your params to:

```
params="[id: item.id]"
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the controller just has "null" as id =/

Comment: What URL does your browser dev tools show is being loaded?

Comment: It's always redirecting to /ProjectName/userRecipe/delete. Instead of adding the parameter. :/

Comment: Okay @tim_yates it turns out your solution actually helped solve the problem, the subsequent issue is now resolved and was not related to the question. Thanks! :)